# docker-compose up -d doesn't run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker version:
`docker --version Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289`

Docker compose version: `docker-compose -v  docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`

My docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3'
sevices:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: docker.io/jenkins 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    network:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Error:

```
[jenkins@jenkins jenkins-data]$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
'sevices' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
[jenkins@jenkins jenkins-data]$
```

Have already tried by changing version in docker-compose.yaml file to 3.1, 3.2, 1.29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the r in services on line 2

Comment: Can't image this was the reason. :(
Also, I want to know one thing when my docker-compose version is 1.29.2 why we use version as '3' in yaml file. I am following a tutorial to get started with and it is not explain there.

Comment: 3 is the docker-compose file format.
1.29.2 is the docker-compose version.
There is some slightly different syntax between docker-compose file format versions